# Beginner Model Ideas

Tags: modeling

Been off and on using Blender and was one of those guys that jump into it and just looked at tutorial after tutorial and really didn't learn anything.  I am following Blender Guru tutorials and they are really good in that it teaches you the whys and have found it very helpful.  I am doing this more as a hobby and am looking to sharpen my modeling skills.  I am looking for a challenging beginner model (not a car) that poses all the beginner problems that need to be overcome.

Does anyone have a suggestion on type of models or models that you did starting off that when you look back said..."wow that was a great project that I learned a lot!".

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://blenderartists.org is a better place for subjective or opinion based questions

Comment: When I was taking Blender lessons my teacher made me model a chair, and I think it's a great way to start. Make 10 chairs, wooden chairs, office chairs, etc. It's a great way to start. Then a whole room full of objects. Then a city.

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad. This site works best for focused questions and answers and is not meant for opinions or open ended discussions. To understand how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] section. Particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning blender as well. The one tutorial that really inspired me was making billiard balls and animating them. Here are the links :
1. this one was the one I used to get me started, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGh8tTHAL4o&t=2127s)

2. This is a link to my animation, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMIC0SE1rmY)

Hope you enjoy it as much as I did when I first started like 6 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

For me I took a very simple, recognizable iconic everyday object (m&m candies) and started with the basics (how do I make the shapes and colors) then kept pushing myself to evolve to photorealism.  It’s been really fun and the thing I like about starting very simple and challenging myself to keep stepping forward is that I UNDERSTAND what I’m doing as opposed to following a Blender expert’s impossible node setup.  I actually get what my nodes are doing, and how and why they are doing it.  I’ve gotten some great help here when I stumble.

Obviously this isn’t going to help you tackle advanced hard surface modeling but for textures and lighting it’s great.

For some advanced hard surface modeling search YouTube for Darrin Lyle.  He has a few great series that I really got into.  He’s easy to listen to and gentle for beginners but himself an expert.

Tutor4U is another great YouTube channel.

[image: Simple beginning stages]

[image: Progress!]